# jQuery ajax post success - saving data to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function getReport(name,x) {
    var xArr = [];
    var yArr = [];
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        //async: false,
        //dataType: "json",
        url: "reportAjax.php",
        data: "name="+ name,
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            var chartDesc = json.INFO.DESC;
            $.each(json.RESULT, function(i, object) {
                $.each(object, function(property, value) {
                    //alert(property + "=" + value);
                    if (property == x) {
                        xArr.push(value);
                    }
                    else {
                        yArr.push(parseInt(value));
                    }

                });
            });                
        }
    }); 
    console.log(xArr);
    console.log(yArr);
    console.log(chartDesc);
    drawChart(xArr,yArr,chartDesc);
}
```

For some reason, I can see in the `console.log` the values of `xArr` and `yArr`, but I get `chartDesc is not defined` for `chartDesc`.

If I move the `console.log(chartDesc)` line to be under this line `var chartDesc = json.INFO.DESC` I can see it properly.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring the `chartDesc` variable inside the AJAX callback function, so it is outside the scope of your later reference to it.

To fix this, remove the `var` from the start of the line, and instead declare it at the top of the function with the `xArr` and `yArr` variables:

```
var xArr = [];
var yArr = [];
var chartDesc = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

`chartDesc` variable scope is tied to the `success` function, that's why outside it, the variable is `undefined`.
in `Javascript` functions create scopes for variables defined with `var`

Answer (score 0):

make your

```
console.log(xArr);
console.log(yArr);
```

within `success` function. and declire `chartDesc` variable outside of success function,

console log outside of success function execute immediately when function called, but it takes some time to insert value of `xArr` and `yArr` due to success function execution. so you get nothing in you log.